# How to know what type to cast a JObject to when deserializing a JSON string

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I know there have been quite a few questions on deserialization using Newtonsoft in the past, but I haven't been able to find something that exactly matches my situation. (If I did unintentionally ask a duplicate question please let me know, I find it hard to believe that I'm the first person to encounter this type of a situation).

I have an object  structure like this:

```
public class Logger
    {
        public List<MethodAPI> List { get; set; }
    }

    private class MethodAPI
    {
        public string MethodName { get; set; }
        public List<Parameter> Parameters { get; set; }
    }
```

And now for the type I was having trouble deserializing. If I do something like the following:

```
    public class Parameter
    {
        public IProduct data { get; set; }
    }
```

then deserialization works just fine. However, I don't really know what type `data` will be until runtime. If, however, I do the following:

```
public class Parameter
{
   public object data { get; set; }
}
```

obviously when I go to deserialize this Newtonsoft has no way of resolving what type this should actually be. Thus, it just makes it a `JObject`.

Normally, I'd just write a custom converter. However, I'm not sure exactly how to implement the `ReadJson` method in this case.

```
public class ParameterConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            return objectType.Equals(typeof(Parameter));
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            // I'd rather just do serializer.Deserialize<Parameter>(reader) here but that'll cause a stack overflow exception
            object obj = serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            Parameter param = (obj as JObject).ToObject<Parameter>();

            // This works great if I know that I'm converting this to IProduct, but is there an elegant way to figure out what type to use here?
            // I have to pass the serializer here because the serializer can "map" IProduct and several of its "child" types to its implementation
            param.data = (param.data as JObject).ToObject(typeof(IProduct), serializer);
            return param;
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            // Serialization's no problem
            serializer.Serialize(writer, value);
        }
    }
```

As I mentioned in the code comments, the part I'm confused about is how to determine what type the original object was based on the original JSON. Does anyone have a suggestion as to non-hideous ways of doing this?

Comment: Maybe `new JsonSerializerSettings() {  TypeNameHandling = ......}`

Comment: @L.B Thanks, that seems to do exactly what I need - doesn't even require the custom converter.

Comment: @L.B If you post as an answer I'll be glad to accept/upvote

Comment: EJoshuaS, you can accept your own answer. No need to repeat the same thing....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @L.B. on this one - I'm slightly embarrassed to have missed this, but all I needed to do was

```
new JsonSerializerSettings() { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects }
```

No need for the custom converter.

I'll leave this up for now in case someone else finds it useful.

Answer (score 0):

One of the beautiful new things in c# is the new declared type `dynamic`.  This is essentially the same thing as declaring a `var` in JavaScript (if you're familiar).

**Example**

Your class would be:

```
public class Parameter
{
   public dynamic data { get; set; }
}
```

Now in code I could create an instance of it and use it however I want:

```
Parameter param = new Parameter();
string foo = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(some_object);

// If you know the object type (in this case the object type is IProduct)
param.data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IProduct>(foo);

// If you don't know the object type
param.data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(foo, new ExpandoObjectConverter());
```

An expando object is a C# class that allows you to make dynamic objects that allow you to call any method and it'll evaluate it at run time.

**For example**

```
dynamic foo = new ExpandoObject();
// Creates a member variable named bar
foo.bar = "Hello, World!";
// Throws an runtime error because bar2 is undefined
Console.WriteLine(foo.bar2);
```

I don't know if this is your problem but it's helpful to know anyway :)